# Is it possible to do a wx.TextCtrl with no border?

Tags: python, wxpython

I want to do a wx.TextCtrl with no border usign wxpython :P
How can I do it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How about `wx.BORDER_NONE` as in:

```
t1 = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "my text", style=wx.BORDER_NONE)
```